# New books on Dojo in 2011/12

Tags: dojo

Is anyone aware of any new books coming out on Dojo? All the books I've checked out so far are a couple years old. I heard that authors are waiting for 1.7 to be released as there are a lot of changes from 1.6. The documentation and tutts on the site are getting much better, thanks to sitepen but I always like to have a good book to peruse on the bus.